# how to remove 404 error in nextjs or react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to implement `localization` with `base path` .but I am getting `404`.I am also using `rewrite` in `next.config` file.still getting `404` why

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-keldysh-xfmj6?file=/next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: "/customers",
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:siteid/customers/",
        destination: "http://localhost:3000/customers/:siteid" // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      },
      {
        source: "/:slug/customers/:sg",
        destination: "http://localhost:3000/customers/:slug/:sg" // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      }
    ];
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "fr", "nl-NL", "fa"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US"
  }
};
```

when I use this url

**https://xfmj6-3005.sse.codesandbox.io/fr/customers** it should open it component **https://xfmj6-3005.sse.codesandbox.io/customers/fr** as I already given in configuration .why 404

it should show  this instead of `404`

[image]